# how to make oracle UTL_HTTP.request asynchronous?

Tags: database, oracle, http, asynchronous

I have a job that runs periodically , and I am not interested in the response ??

is there anyway to make the calling convention , request without waiting for the response ??

Regards,

Comment: Your requirement actually is a relaxation of asynchronous processing sice you are not interested in the response at all - effectively you fire a REST webservice call dismissing any response. Set a short timeout and catch the timeout exception with a null handler. Another option (actually preferred given the api description, but i haven't tested it) is to call `utl_http.begin_request` followed by `utl_http.end_request` which disregards any possible server response.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the API request as a procedure and called the PL/SQL output in the DBMS_JOB method.

```
 L_REQUEST:=' DECLARE
            BEGIN
            SCOTT.PROCEDURE_SENDER ('''|| ITEMS || ''',1);
            
            COMMIT;
        END;';
        
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (L_REQUEST);
     DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT (L_JOB, L_REQUEST);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (L_JOB);
```

Comment: I think even so , your procedure will only start the request on another db session via the scheduler and would still wait for the response as utl_http will be synchronous